# Autowiring an @Component annotated class from within another @Component annotated class in spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, autowired

I have a bean called InjectionTest and it is annotated with `@Component`.
When i autowire this bean within a controller it works fine. 
But when i try to use it in another class with `@Component` annotation, autowire does not work and i get a null pointer exception. Any ideas ?

InjectionTest class

```
@Component
public class InjectionTest {

    private String word;

    public String getWord() {
        return "test";
     }

     public void setWord(String word) {
       this.word = word;
     }
}
```

Below is the controller class method which works fine

```
@Controller
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    AppConfig appConfig;

    @Autowired
    InjectionTest injectionTest;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/user/authentication", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String authentication(HttpServletResponse res, @RequestParam Map<String, String> allRequestParams,
            HttpServletRequest req) {

        //I dont get an exception in the below line it works fine..
        System.out.println(injectionTest.getWord());
        ....
    }
}
```

Below is the component which i want to autowire the InjectionTest class and get null pointer exception while creation...

```
@Component
public class HelloComponent {

    @Autowired
    InjectionTest injectionTest;

    public HelloComponent(){
    //I get null pointer exception in the below line.
        injectionTest.getWord();
    }

}
```

> SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'helloComponent' defined in file
>   [C:\Repo.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp3\wtpwebapps\AdaRvmWeb\WEB-INF\classes\tr\com\simroll\ada\rvm\web\entity\HelloComponent.class]:
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [tr.com.simroll.ada.rvm.web.entity.HelloComponent]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

I am really confused. Is there an order or something while creation. If so how can i fix this problem? Thanks..

Comment: How you load `HelloComponent`?

Comment: Yes i get an exception while creating HelloComponent.. @Jens

Comment: Yes that i do understand. But I ask *HOW* do youcreate it?

Comment: I just start the server and i get the above exception.. @Jens

Comment: This happens because you are using the field `injectionTest` inside the **constructor** of your class `HelloComponent`. At that moment, Spring has not yet had the chance to autowire the field yet.